# Angular services "lifecycle" in lazy loading

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, lazy-loading, lifecycle

We know that Angular services do not have lifecycles as components have. My question is about 'destructing' a service when it has done.

In my application, there is a lazy module `Module A` which provides a service `Service A` when it is loaded (only `Module A` needs `Service A`). 
When done, I call another lazy module and `Service A` is no longer necessary, but it is kept by the Angular injector. Being more specific, Angular injector tree has now a single root injector and a child injector for `Module A`.

**My question**: as the service is kept running, should I create a function to destroy it (unsubscribe, clean arrays etc) and call it when `Module A` is being closed or there is another way to destroy it?

I've searched [Angular Injector Class](https://angular.io/api/core/Injector) but it doesn't have some `delete` method to delete specific services.

Comment: Related question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462243/does-the-angular-2-router-unload-the-previous-lazy-loaded-module . Since module providers aren't going to be destroyed, this likely means that you should clean up lazy-loaded service as any other.

Comment: Or you implement the services stateless. To transport data between components you can usw "scoped" services (provided services on comp. level)

Comment: @moohkooh, could you explain to me what is "services on comp. level"?

Comment: Hi. That are services that a provided by the Component
@Component({
    selector: 'test-cmp',
    template: '<h1>Huhu</h1>',
    providers: [ {provide: TOKEN, useClass: MyService} ]
})


This service is know with this TOKEN underneath the component available. With Injector.get(TOKEN), you can inject this service.

 
export const TOKEN = new InjectionToken<Service>();

Answer (score 1):

If you register the service in a component, such as the primary component of Module A instead of in Module A directly, then the service will be destroyed when the component is destroyed.

Comment: I guess the OP says that the service belongs to child module injector, not component.

Comment: Good to know that I can provide services inside a component. In my case, it's not possible because the service makes a WebSocket connection and I should make it only one time.